# How to redirect to the login page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am facing an issue while setting up private route middleware in React. When accessing a private route, I invoke the 'RequireAuth' component that validates if the authentication token is valid. The dilemma arises because the validation is asynchronous and alters the state of the context. As a result, I have two renderings: the first one returning 'null' and the second one the actual value.

I considered alternatives, such as using another state to indicate that the asynchronous method is loading, thus avoiding the validation in the middleware during the first rendering where the value is still null. It worked, but I don't think it's ideal! It's important that the context be updated when the 'user' state changes, but I am unsure if two renderings are really necessary for this type of validation, where I only need to know if the token is valid or not.

Initializing the 'user' state with the actual value instead of 'null' is an option, but that would result in multiple API requests with each context state update, given the absence of useEffect.

The first context return, and the second one after the asynchronous method:

[image]

How it is currently happening:

````js
const RoutesApp = () => {
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<RequireAuth><Home /></RequireAuth>} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
};

export default RoutesApp;

--------------------------------------------------
export const RequireAuth = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
const auth = useAuth(); // Hook by Auth Context

if (!auth.user) {
  return <Navigate to="/login" />
}
return children;

};

--------------------------------------------------
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const api = useApi();

useEffect(() => {
  validToken()
}, []);

...

const validToken = async () => {
  const storageData = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  if (storageData) {
    const data = await api.validateToken(storageData);
    if (data.user) {
      setUser(data.user);
    }
  }
}

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={ user, ...}> 
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
}
```
````

Comment: the question is "how to redirect to the login page with react router". There is a useNavigate hook exactly for this. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: If you don't know and have the current authentication status on the initial render and it is set later after some asynchronous logic then OFC you are going to have *at least* two render cycles on your route protection component. Just handle the initial render (*and any subsequent rerenders*) where the auth state isn't set yet with a loading condition.

Answer (score -1):

Use `useNavigate()`.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const authenticationToken = getAuthenticationToken();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!authenticationToken) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }, [authenticationToken]);
}
```

etc

Comment: This isn't much different than what the OP is already doing, except in your solution the effect runs ***at the end*** of the render cycle and so the protected content will be allowed to render once before the navigation action is effected. This doesn't answer the question asked by the OP either.